# Amplify pull error rename amplify to amplify-backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

So I successfully installed amplify cli with `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` then ran `amplify pull` on a cloned repository branch.

I was going through all the questions when I accidentally terminated the terminal in the middle of it, and now `amplify pull` no longer worked properly.

I deleted the clone on my local machine and made a fresh clone again, running `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` and `amplify pull`, now it gives an error `EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\........\amplify' -> 'C:\........\amplify-backup'`

Should I just rename the folder? Will it break anything if I eventually merge this with the main branch? Thank you!

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This different sequence of commands worked:

```
$ npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
$ amplify init   #this asked me to select an existing environment and set up an AWS profile
$ amplify env pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by terminating the react native local server that had been running.